# Unable to SSH from inside Kubernetes container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a container running inside Kubernetes that I created using Helm and a Dockerfile. I am trying to run an application that connects to another machine outside of my cluster over SSH, but the connection always times out.

I am able to open a shell connection to it with `kubectl exec -it my-container --namespace my-namespace -- /bin/bash` from which I can use `http` without any trouble, but `ping` and `ssh` both hang and timeout.

What do I need in order to enable outbound SSH connections from my container?

Comment: are you using any cloud provider? have you checked the network outbound rules from the firewall?

Comment: If you install OpenSSH server in your container and expose the port? If not, you can read [Dockerize SSH Service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/).

Comment: Please clarify: are you using a http proxy for outbound traffic? Is your default gateway reachable from this Docker container using ping for example? Is your edge router allowing outbound traffic for 22/tcp and icmp protocols? Are any other tcp ports reachable i.e. ftp or external proxy on 3128/tcp or 8080/tcp via telnet command from this Docker container? And regards to

Comment: [Diego Velez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540883/diego-velez) comment, what kind of cloud provider do you use to set up your Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: I'm running everything in Azure. @DiegoVelez you were right, there was a clean up service running in Azure that was disabling/blocking all outbound traffic except http. I added a rule to not disable outbound traffic on port 22 and it works now.